# Global styling in vue using @egoist/vue-emotion

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, global, styling

I'm using version 2 of vue and @egoist/vue-emotion for styling my jsx components. I want to add a feature that user can change the background color of my application globally but I don't know how to do it.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { Component } from 'vue-property-decorator'
import { styled } from '@egoist/vue-emotion'
import {CustomInput} from './components/CustomInput'
import { createGlobalStyle } from '@egoist/vue-emotion'
const Container = styled('div')`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90vh;
`
const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
  body {
    background: {{inputValue}};
  }
`

@Component({
  components: {
    CustomInput,
    Container,
    GlobalStyle
  },
})
export class App extends Vue {
  inputValue = 'black'
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <GlobalStyle/>
      <Container>
    <CustomInput />
  </Container>
  </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I want you to help me that how can i access my data variable so when it changes I change my style state.